# Why is my css background image not showing on mobile?

Tags: css

I have viewed several answers on SO related to this question and have used that to write my css code as such (I was using short-hand before):

```
#intro {
    background-image: url(http://www.trbimg.com/img-5a98709c/turbine/ct-met-illinois-legislature-marijuana-20180301); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}
```

This works fine on my computer and in developer tools on Chrome when I resize the window or change the view to, say, iPhone X.

When I use my actual iPhone to go to the site, only a gray background displays, no image at all. I've tried in both Chrome and Safari.

Does anyone have some insight as to why that might be?

What I have tried:

1. Viewed similar questions on SO which helped me re-write my CSS without using the shorthand `background`
2. Stored the image on my server and shrunk it so it had a width of 1000px (half of its original width)

I plan on actually storing the image on my server in the future but I figured if anyone has the time to help me out a link to the large image online would be best.

**Edit:**

I have put together a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yWYoVM) for the #intro element.

Comment: And if you load the image URL directly into the browser? Do you get an error?

Comment: Trying to look up the image results in a "Not Found" being displayed.
Also, there is no extension for the image specified in your CSS. I'm fairly certain it needs that to work

Comment: You omitted the default code "background-size: cover;". Why?  Though is has very strong browser support! https://caniuse.com/#search=background-size

Comment: No, the image loads if I navigate to that URL in the browser. It also shows up fine on PC for me.

Comment: How large is the #intro element when viewed on your phone?

Comment: _“I plan on actually storing the image on my server in the future but I figured if anyone has the time to help me out a link to the large image online would be best.”_ - not necessarily, that image hosting service(?) might block “hot linking” under specific conditions, as most of them tend to do. You should test this with an image properly hosted on your own server first (if you have not done so yet), if only to exclude that as a possible error reason.

Comment: @MrLister I think I indeed made a slight copy paste error. It's indeed there. Sorry bout that :)

Comment: I omitted `background-size: cover` as that was a suggestion in another question, if I add it I see no change in behavior.

Comment: I did try storing the image on my server with the same result (this was when I was playing with size, scaling it down by half).

Comment: Well then you need to give us a proper [mcve], that minimal snippet of CSS alone is not helpful in figuring this out.

Comment: Are you using SSL for your site? If so, the phone might think using http for resources is not safe.

Comment: I do use SSL, but am confused as to why it still wouldn't work if I store the image on my server. I would love to create a code pen or similar, but I'm relying on plenty of external libraries (jQuery, bootstrap, mdbootstrap, etc.) - not sure if I can even set one up?

Comment: Both jsfiddle and codepen allow you to embed external libraries. (Former has “Resources” in the left sidebar, in the latter it is done via the pen settings.)

Comment: Okay I think we can try this: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yWYoVM)